# Update Column Trigger in SQL Server - error multi-part Identifier cannot be bound

Tags: sql-server, syntax, triggers

I am trying to find the correct syntax to create a simple update trigger.

I consistently get the error message

**The multi-part identifier "AD.AgencyId" could not be bound.**

Here is the trigger, The [FullName] column of AgencyDivision should contain it's parent's (Agency) Name as well [Agency].Name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trUpdateAgencyDivisionFullName] 
ON [dbo].[AgencyDivision] FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    UPDATE AD
    SET AD.FullName = A.Name + ' , ' + AD.DivisionName
    FROM AgencyDivision as AD, inserted AS i
    JOIN Agency AS A
    ON AD.AgencyId = A.Id
    WHERE i.Id = AD.Id
END
```

Are there any syntax changes I can make to solve this?  Can this JOIN structure work in triggers?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds too obvious, but can you double check that the AgencyDivision table has an AgencyId on it?

Also, just from a pure syntax perspective, I would change it to:

```
UPDATE AD 
SET AD.FullName = A.Name + ' , ' + AD.DivisionName 
FROM AgencyDivision as AD
INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON i.Id = AD.Id 
INNER JOIN Agency AS A ON AD.AgencyId = A.Id
```

In your version, you are mixing ANSI and theta syntax for your joins.

Comment: Yes, AgencyDivision has AgencyId.  Thanks for the quick and correct answer.